# FB.api links.get can't work with short name accounts

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I use this code:

```
FB.api({ 
    method: 'links.get',
    uid: user_uid,
    limit: 100
},function(response){
    var response = response[0];
    if(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I can't get response from callback of this function, if people with mentioned  use short name( instead of ?id=100000000).

I'm getting user id using this code.

But it works only if user doesn't have short name:

`FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response){
    user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
});`

But it works only if user doesn't have short name.

How can i listen event from people with a short name?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Name has nothing to do with it. `response.authResponse.userID` will always return the `user_id` not `user_name`. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I know that i get uid 1000**********. But i can't listen event if user have short name. I don't know why...

Comment: We have 2 accounts.
First is acc with a http://facebook.com/122222222000
Second is http://facebook.com/examplename
We can't listen event in a second account.
We get 2 id from 2 acc, but we can listen only first acc.